# Return multiple string format

Tags: java

I am new in this forum. I am stuck on a part of my code. 
One method of my code give me this information :

getFullAddress() should return the address as a formatted String,  one item per line:
e.g.:

```
23 High Street
Newcastle
NE1 1NE
```

The thing is that i am stuck, i tried everything but nothing works.

Here is my code :

```
/**
* Write a description of class Address here.
* 
* @author Bento Xavier
* @version 10/17/2015
*/
public class Address
{
  private String postcode;
  private String street;
  private String town;

 public Address(String street, String town, String postcode)
 {
   this.street = street;
   this.town = town;
   this.postcode = postcode;
 }

 public String getFullAddress()
 {
    String fullAddress = "";
    fullAddress = ;
 }

 public String getPostcode()
 {
   return postcode;
 }

public String getStreet()
{
   return street;
}

 public String getTown()
 {
   return town;
 }

 public void printAddress()
 {
   System.out.println(street + " \n" + town + " \n" + postcode );
 }

 public void setFullAddress(String street, String town, String postcode)
 {
   this.street = street;
   this.town = town;
   this.postcode = postcode;
 }

 public void setPostcode(String postcode)
 {
   this.postcode = postcode;
 }

 public void setStreet(String street)
 {
   this.street = street;
 }

 public void setTown(String town)
 {
   this.town = town;
 }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning anything in `getFullAddress()`. Change `getFullAddress` method to this:

```
public String getFullAddress() {
    final String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); //final indicates the variable will not change
    return getStreet() + separator  + getTown() + separator  + getPostcode();
}
```

I suggest you use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` over `\n`, because `\n` will not correctly work on every operating system. Getting the line separator using `System.getProperty()` returns the correct newline character for every OS.

Comment: Format sure seems a lot cleaner, or at *least* set the line separator to an intermediate value.

Comment: I didn't want to complicate the code too much, because it is a beginner question. But you're right about saving the line separator, no need to get it three times. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Just concat the string with newline characters between them:

```
public String getFullAddress() {
    return String.format("%s%n%s%n", getStreet(), getTown(), getPostcode());
}
```